# Cmds.radioMenuItemCollection - get selected

Tags: python, radio-button, maya, popupmenu, maya-api

Hey all I am trying to get the name of the selected menuItem(radioButton) in a popupMenu. I know in cmds.radioCollection they have a flag called "select" but for cmds.radioMenuItemCollection the flag select doesn't exist. How can I get the name of the selected option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ADSK forgot to expose all the controls on that one! It doesn't report as a regular `radioCollection`. so the only workaround is something like this:

```
cmds.window( menuBar=True )
q = cmds.menu( label='Position' )
r = cmds.radioMenuItemCollection()
x =cmds.menuItem( label='Top', radioButton=False )
y = cmds.menuItem( label='Middle', radioButton=False )
z = cmds.menuItem( label='Bottom', radioButton=True )
cmds.showWindow()

selected = max ([t if cmds.menuItem(t, q=True, rb=True) else None for t in  (x,y,z)])
```

Comment: I think I understand but I am trying to print the menu item. And when I try and print "selected" it doesn't come back with the name of selected.